# Need help configuring DLQ for Lambda triggered by SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'd like to receive an email if my Lambda fails. The Lambda is triggered via SNS (which is triggered by SES).

When I publish to the SNS Topic, the Lambda runs and throws an error (for testing) due to a missing package. I see from the console logs that the Lambda runs 3 times.

I have an SQS queue attached to the `Redrive policy (dead-letter queue)` of the SNS Topic's subscription (that triggers the lambda).

```
{
  "deadLetterTargetArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:myproj-sns-topic-dlq"
}
```

I tested, and things didn't work. I noticed a warning in the AWS console for the SNS Topic's subscription:

> Dead-letter queue (redrive policy) permissions The Amazon SQS queue
> specified as the dead-letter queue for your subscription (redrive
> policy) doesn't permit deliveries from topics. To allow an Amazon SNS
> topic to send messages to an Amazon SQS queue, you must create an
> Amazon SQS queue policy.

Following the steps [Subscribing an Amazon SQS queue to an Amazon SNS topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/subscribe-sqs-queue-to-sns-topic.html), I added the 2nd statement to my SQS queue's `Access policy`:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:myproj-sns-topic-dlq"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:myproj-sns-topic-dlq",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:myproj-snstopic"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The `Principal` was `{"Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"}`, but that results in a warning in the AWS console saying it can't test permissions. I tested anyway and it didn't work. (Lambda runs 3 times, but nothing gets put in the DLQ.)

I set the Principal to * for now (per snippet above). That eliminates the warning in the console, but things still don't work.

My goal it to have the event drop into the SQS DLQ after the Lambda fails. I have an alarm on that queue that will notify me by email...

Edit: added missing condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SNS redrive to Dead letter queue not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522952/sns-redrive-to-dead-letter-queue-not-working)

Comment: @fedonev Oh, that looks very promising. Let me see if that works.

Comment: You might also find the Lambda [asynchronous invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) docs helpful.  The async invocation integration that SNS uses has 2 queue error-handling options:  a SQS [error destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-async-destinations) pattern or the older [Lambda DLQ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-dlq) pattern.

Comment: @fedonev Want to put the above in the answer area so I can credit you? As a quick test, I set an SNS topic in the DLQ area of the lambda's asynchronous configuration. For testing, I also had to set the max age to 1 minute in the retries area. I poked the lambda, it failed and I received email via the SNS topic. Thanks for the links, I'll look into those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @fedonev, the SNS Subscription's (for lambda) DLQ is used when the event cannot be delivered. If the event is delivered (but the Lambda fails), you can use Lambda's async event DLQ or wire-up the 'on failed' destination of the Lambda.

I'm using AWS Amplify and decided to use the Lambda's "async" DLQ as opposed to a lambda destination.

Step 1 - Add a custom category to add:

- SQS (dlq) to save the failed attampt's event
- CloudWatch Alarm to watch the SQS resource
- SNS Topic and Subscription(s) used by the Alarm

And "Output" the SQS queue's ARN which is needed by the Lambda.

Step 2 - Add a "DeadLetterConfig" to the Lambda that pushes fails into the above queue.

`amplify add custom`

name: LambdaAlarm

File: `amplify/backend/custom/LambdaAlarm/LambdaAlarm-cloudformation-template.json`

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "env": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "SQSDLQ": {
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
      "Properties": {
        "QueueName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "myproject-lambdafailed-dlq",
              {
                "Fn::Select": [
                  3,
                  {
                    "Fn::Split": [
                      "-",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "-",
              {
                "Ref": "env"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "MessageRetentionPeriod": 1209600,
        "VisibilityTimeout": 5432,
        "SqsManagedSseEnabled": false
      }
    },
    "SNSTOPIC": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
      "Properties": {
        "TopicName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "myproject-lambda-failed-alarm-topic",
              {
                "Fn::Select": [
                  3,
                  {
                    "Fn::Split": [
                      "-",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "-",
              {
                "Ref": "env"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "SNSSubscriptionEmailJoeAtGmail": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
      "Properties": {
        "Protocol": "email",
        "TopicArn": {
          "Ref": "SNSTOPIC"
        },
        "Endpoint": "yourname+myprojectalert@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    "SNSSubscriptionEmailJillAtQuad": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
      "Properties": {
        "Protocol": "email",
        "TopicArn": {
          "Ref": "SNSTOPIC"
        },
        "Endpoint": "jill@stakeholder.com"
      }
    },
    "ALARM": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties": {
        "AlarmName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "myproject-lambda-failed-dlq-alarm",
              {
                "Fn::Select": [
                  3,
                  {
                    "Fn::Split": [
                      "-",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "-",
              {
                "Ref": "env"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "AlarmDescription": "There are messages in the 'Lambda Failed' dead letter queue.",
        "Namespace": "AWS/SQS",
        "MetricName": "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "QueueName",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "SQSDLQ",
                "QueueName"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "Statistic": "Sum",
        "Period": 60,
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
        "Threshold": 0,
        "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold",
        "AlarmActions": [
          {
            "Ref": "SNSTOPIC"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "SQSDLQArn": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "SQSDLQ",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Description": ""
}
```

Next, update and add the new custom resource as a dependency of the Lambda(s) to monitor.

File: `backend-config.json`

```
"function": {
  "MYLambda": {
    "build": true,
    "dependsOn": [
      {
        "attributes": [
          "SQSDLQArn"
        ],
        "category": "custom",
        "resourceName": "LambdaAlarm"
      }
    ],
    "providerPlugin": "awscloudformation",
    "service": "Lambda"
  },
},
```

In the Lambda(s) you want to monitor, make 3 changes to the cloudformation:

1. Pull in the output variable (`customLambdaAlarmSQSDLQArn`) from your custom category and add it to the `Parameters`
2. Add the `DeadLetterConfig` property to the Lambda
3. Add a policy to the LambdaExecutionRole

File: `amplify/backend/function/MyLambda/MyLambda-cloudformation-template.json`

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "...",
  "Parameters": {
    ...snip...
    "customLambdaAlarmSQSDLQArn": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    ...snip...
  },
  "Conditions": {...snip...},
  "Resources": {
    "LambdaFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Metadata": {...snip},
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {...snip...},
        "Handler": "index.handler",
        "FunctionName": {...snip...},
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {...snip...}
        },
        "Role": {...snip...},
        "Runtime": "nodejs18.x",
        "Architectures": ["arm64"],
        "Layers": [],
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 120,
        "DeadLetterConfig": {
          "TargetArn": {
            "Ref": "customLambdaAlarmSQSDLQArn"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": {...snip...},
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "custom-lambda-execution-policy",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Sid": "AllowSQSSendMessage",
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "SQS:SendMessage"
                  ],
                  "Resource": {
                    "Ref": "customLambdaAlarmSQSDLQArn"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {...snip...}
      }
    },
    "lambdaexecutionpolicy": {...snip...},
    "AmplifyResourcesPolicy": {...snip...},
    "CustomLambdaExecutionPolicy": {...snip...}
  },
  "Outputs": {...snip...}
}
```

Finally, due to an Amplify quirk you must `amplify env checkout dev` because you manually touched the `backend-config.json` file.

Then you can deploy your changes. The above is not specific to AWS Amplify.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/get-notified-specific-lambda-function-error-patterns-using-cloudwatch/), you can use a CloudWatch Log filter to parse a log for a Lambda function and get an email notification.

[image: Lambda Error Email Notifications]

To implement this solution, you must create the following:

- An SNS topic
- An IAM role
- A Lambda function
- A CloudWatch log trigger

Comment: Good point. This solution would work but may be better suited to detecting internal/non-fatal Lambda errors. My personal preference is to hook up to the Lambda's failure mechanism directly.

Comment: If you mean writing the email logic in the Lambda itself, I used to do it like that. I found if the Lambda time-out or the code does not reach the email logic the no one get notified.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I prefer the solution I described in my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for sharing and having this discussion. I would need to take your solution for a test drive when I find an opportunity for it to learn more.